How to use defineAsyncComponent with Vite and Vue component :is?
Could someone explain to me how to use defineAsyncComponent with vite component :is? I'm migrating from vue-cli to Vite and have uncountered an issue where component imported via defineAsyncComponent are not rendering in the layout
For example here is my code:
<template>
  <component :is="icon.icon" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed, defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";

const ICONS = {
  star: {
    icon: defineAsyncComponent(() => import("@heroicons/vue/solid/StarIcon"));
  }
};
 
const icon = computed(() => ICONS.star);
</script>

Problem is that the result of the import() in vue-cli is as esmodule with a default getter, but in Vite, it is an object with a default property
To make it work I did this, but I feel like I'm doing something wrong.
defineAsyncComponent(async () => (await import("@heroicons/vue/solid/StarIcon")).default);

"vue": "^3.3.4",
"@heroicons/vue": "^1.0.6",
"vite": "^5.2.12",

defineAsyncComponent supports both a function that returns a promise of a component and a promise of module object as an argument, but only for ES modules.
The problem is specific to the package. @heroicons/vue@1.0.6 provides CommonJS modules for each component like @heroicons/vue/solid/StarIcon. They can be imported as default ESM import with module interop but may not satisfy the requirements in defineAsyncComponent, as this depends on a way the bundler implements it.
So (await import("@heroicons/vue/solid/StarIcon")).default is a workaround will work with both CJS and ES modules and can be generally recommended for such cases.

I get it.
but if you pull out the StarIcon file and put it next to it and try to import it, it works as it should (just like with vue-cli).

Can you clarify what does your code look like in this case it's working?
